# In MVC .net project im getting error as "JavaScript runtime error: Error: Cannot find module "moment" "

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, momentjs

I have deployed the code in MVC Dot Net core project that was developed Through Razor and C# with MVC opened that in Visual studio 2017 Community. - Once I opened the solution of the "Advaxis.Norm.sln" file I got solution explorer in right side first I have rebuild the Solution and run the solution but it's showing error refer the image.

[image]

Comment: What is that code ? this is not c#, not razor template cshtml ... can you show us more files/codes/environment ?

Comment: I think this is Angular2/4. So you need to install moment.js.

Comment: Yes it was an angular 2 code file.... but i have opened the solution in visual studio 2017 community .

Comment: As @HarshaKN said, you need to install moment.js. Have you run an npm install command? Does the package.json include a reference to moment.js?

Comment: @GGO: typescript, but you seem to get it already

Comment: Yes Thanks..... @GGO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an angular package.
Open the package nuget manager (right click on your project > "Manage nuget package") and install "Moment.js" package on your project.

Package link : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moment.js/